# Spark Job running even after spark Master process is killed

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

We are working on spark cluster where spark job(s) are getting submitted successfully even after spark "Master" process is killed.

Here is the complete details about what we are doing.

### process details :-

jps
19560 NameNode
18369 QuorumPeerMain
22414 Jps
20168 ResourceManager
22235 Master

and we submitted one spark job to this Master using the command like

spark-1.6.1-bin-without-hadoop/bin/spark-submit --class com.test.test --master yarn-client --deploy-mode  client test.jar  -incomingHost hostIP

where hostIP having correct ip address of the machine running "Master" process.
And after this we are able to see the job in RM Web UI also. 
Now when we kill the "Master" Process , we can see the submitted job is running fine which is expected here as we we are using yarn mode and that job will run without any issue.

Now we killed the "Master" process.
But when we submit once again the same command "spark-submit" pointing to same Master IP which is currently down , we see once more job in RM web ui (host:8088), This we are not able to understand as Spark "Master"  is killed ( and host:8080) the spark UI also does not come.

Please note that we are using "yarn-client" mode as below code

```
sparkProcess = new SparkLauncher()
.......
.setSparkHome(System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"))    
.setMaster("yarn-client")
.setDeployMode("client")
```

Please some can explain me about this behaviour ? Did not found after reading many blogs (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html ) and official docs .
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Please check [cluster overview](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html). As per your description you are running spark application on yarn cluster mode with driver placed in instance where you launch command. The Spark master is related to spark standalone cluster mode which on your case launch command should be similar to

```
spark-submit --master spark://your-spark-master-address:port
```

Comment: Thanks , but the command that we are using includes :-                               spark-1.6.1-bin-without-hadoop/bin/spark-submit --class com.test.test --master yarn-client --deploy-mode  client test.jar  -incomingHost ip_of_master    where we explicitly say deploymode and master to yarn ... any  specific reason of job getting submited successfully without Master ??